# redux subscribe fires but the store object is empty

Tags: redux, subscribe

This issue is related to linking state and store in subscribe method in redux.
Please note, I found many answers in stackoverflow related to react with redux, but this is related to pure redux.

The problem in the code is, inside subscribe method store object is not available. But dispatch works and inside dispatch we can see that store is getting updated too.

How to get store inside subscribe method.

This is my code in a file called redrec.js

```
const {createStore} = require("redux");
const initialState = { age:21 };
const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
{
    if(action.type === 'ADD'){ state.age += 1;  }

    // console.log('Hello' );
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(state) );
    // console.log(state.age);

    return  state;
}
const store = createStore(myReducer);
store.dispatch({type: 'ADD'});
store.subscribe(()=>{

    console.log('Hello' );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store) );
    console.log(store.age);

});
store.dispatch({type: 'ADD'});
```

I execute it with command

```
node redrec.js
```

I am getting the following result

```
Hello
{}
undefined
```

If I uncomment, the commented code, I see this result.

```
Hello
{"age":21}
21
Hello
{"age":22}
22
Hello
{"age":23}
23
Hello
{}
undefined
```

So, how to get state object store ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer.
from store we need to get state with getState method.
Hence inside subscribe method,

change the following

```
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store.getState()) );
    console.log(store.getState().age);
```

Update correct code is

```
const {createStore} = require("redux");
const initialState = { age:21 };
const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
{
    if(action.type === 'ADD'){ state.age += 1;  }

    // console.log('Hello' );
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(state) );
    // console.log(state.age);

    return  state;
}
const store = createStore(myReducer);
store.dispatch({type: 'ADD'});
store.subscribe(()=>{

    console.log('Hello' );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store.getState()) );
    console.log(store.getState().age);

});
store.dispatch({type: 'ADD'});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in redux documentation, redux state is something immutable.

I can see in your reducer you are mutating it and returning mutated value. Instead you need to create a new object and return that.

```
return {
    ...state,
    age: state.age +=1,
};
```

This is because when in your components you map state to props, it will be rendered only if reference of the prop is changed.

Comment: I changed as you mentioned, but still I have the same issue in subscribe method. I cant get it to work without store.getState()